# Server Side Rendering handle Authentication

Tags: angular, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, prerender

I have a website which is based on Angular 4 as front framework,

I needed to improve my website load time, and also fix some SEO issues,
so I decided to use server side rendering,
I'm thinking of two options,

1 ) [prerender](http://prerender.cloud)

2 ) using headless chrome with an API wrapper

I know that [prerender](http://prerender.cloud) service is using 
[headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) underneath and the only reason for me to implement second option is to remove time it takes to forward request to their server through internet.

and question is , how can I use one of these options with pages in my app which needs user to be authenticated,
when my server forward request for "index.html" to "prerender" service, if my user is logged in , his/her access token is stored in his LocalStorage and when "javascript" code initializes, in next request it includes token in Authorization header, so server can authenticate user,
but "prerender" service doesn't access to my user's localstorage.

for now my only solution is using cookie instead of localstorage for storing access tokens.